# Derivation of Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means using a circle

Tags: geometry, inequality, systems-of-equations, circles, means

$$a,b:=\text{positive numbers}\tag{1}$$

I want to derive the following inequality.

$$\underbrace{\sqrt{ab}\leq{a+b\over 2}}_{\text{Inequality of arithmetic and geometric mean}}\tag{2}$$

To derive it, I've reffered the following from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

[image]

Of course I can get$~{a+b\over 2}~$of$~\text{AO}~$since it is a radius of diameter$~a+b~$

But how can I get$~\sqrt{ab}?~$

I tried Pythagorean theorem to apply it here but didn't work.

$$
\begin{cases}
c:=\text{PG}\\
d:=\text{GR}\\
l:=\text{GQ}
\end{cases}\tag{3}
$$

$$a^2+l^2=c^2\tag{4}$$

$$b^2+l^2=d^2\tag{5}$$

$$\therefore~~c^2-a^2=d^2-b^2\tag{6}$$

Comment: Hint: triangles PQG and GQR. Ignore circles for this part.

Comment: The Wikipedia page links to another theorem (calls it the geometric mean theorem) which describes this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $\triangle PQG$ and $\triangle PGR$ are similar since they both have $\angle QPG$ and a right angle
- $\triangle GQR$ and $\triangle PGR$ are similar since they both have $\angle QRG$ and a right angle
- so $\triangle PQG$ and $\triangle GQR$ are similar
- so $\frac{|QP|}{|QG|}=\frac{|QG|}{|QR|}$
- i.e. $|QG|^2=|QP|\,|QR|=ab$
- and thus $|QG|=\sqrt{ab}$